# Structuremap use different concrete type by object type

Tags: structuremap, concrete

I have a default concrete type defined in a registry:

```
    ForRequestedType<IXRepository>()
        .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<CacheXRepository>();
```

The ChaceXRepository has the following constructor:

public class CacheXRepository: IXRepository{

```
    public CacheXRepository(IXRepository xRepository,ICache cacheService){
```

In the constructor it receives an object that has the same interface type as itself, but I want to pass in a different concrete type.

How do I define in the registry that if the type is a CacheXRepository then I want the concrete type for parameter IXRepository to be XRepository, in all other cases IXRepository should resolve to CacheXRepository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the enrichwith method. Then the code will look something like:

```
      ForRequestedType<IXRepository>().TheDefault.Is
            .OfConcreteType<XRepository>()
            .EnrichWith(
            (context, repository) =>
            new CacheXRepository(repository));
```

Look at this page for more info: http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/01/27/interception-techniques-in-structuremap-2-5.aspx

Comment: Thank you!
The code I used based on your reply:

        ForRequestedType<IXRepository>()
            .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<XRepository>()
            .EnrichWith((repository) =>
            new CacheXRepository(repository,ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICache>()));

Answer (score 0):

How about something like (not testet):

```
ForRequestedType<IXRepository>()
  .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<CacheXRepository>()
  .WithCtorArg("xREpository")
  .EqualTo(new XRepository());
```

Im not so familiar with that Structuremap dialect :)

In the version I am using it would be:

```
For<IXRepository>()
  .Use<CacheXRepository>()
  .CtorDependency<IXRepository>("xRepository")
  .IsConcreteType<XRepository>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I ended up using a different answer since it used the syntax in my version. Thank you, I appreciate your help!